# “Missing” memory on ESXi VM

Tags: rhel, memory, vmware

I’m a contractor and have been given a VM with 128 gigs of RAM which the application I’m developing needs.

However, I can at most allocate 74 gigs before the allocation slows down significantly (paging?) and at 86 gigs I get out of memory error.

I created a very simple program that just goes in a loop and allocates memory 1gb at a time, and it also shows the above behaviour.

What’s going on?

Is the VM misconfigured?

I run “top” and press M to sort by memory and nothing is using any significant amount of memory (definitely not the missing 46 gigs worth).

running red hat on ESXi

Answer (score 1):

Obviously the view from a VM is not the whole view; when trying to view the memory using Unix commands in a VM, you have a limited view on the environment and do not have a full view of the hypervisor system.

VMWare has the concept of overcommitment, so if you are seeing this behaviour either someone gave more memory than the hypervisor has, or some other VMs on that host are competing for that memory; and the slow you see is probably the hypervisor using swap in lieu of RAM.

In one case, or another, what it matters to you is that hypervisor most certainly does not have the full RAM asked/does not have it available for your VM to use.

So I am afraid you will really have to see and/or talk with the admins responsible for that VMWare host.

See [vmware technical journal - Memory Overcommitment in the ESX Server](https://labs.vmware.com/vmtj/memory-overcommitment-in-the-esx-server) for more details.

> ESX allows users to power on virtual machines (VMs) with a total
>   configured memory that exceeds the memory available on the physical
>   machine. This is called memory overcommitment.
>
> Overcommitment is the ability to allocate more virtual resources than
>   available physical resources. ESX Server offers users the ability to
>   overcommit memory and CPU resources on a physical machine.
>
> Similar to traditional OSes, ESX allows VMs to power on with a total
>   configured memory size that may exceed the memory available to ESX.
>   For the purpose of discussion in this article, the memory installed in
>   an ESX Server is called ESX memory. If VMs consume all the ESX memory,
>   then ESX will reclaim memory from VMs.
>
> Memory overcommitment does not necessarily lead to performance loss in
>   a guest OS or its applications. Experimental results presented in this
>   paper with two real-life workloads show gradual performance
>   degradation when ESX is progressively overcommitted.